# RestKit in-memory mappings using multiple root keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, restkit, restkit-0.20

Let's say for example that we have a response like this:

```
{
   "authors":[
      {
         "id":"9",
         "name":"Some User",
         "email":"some@email.com"
      }
   ],
   "comments":[
      {
         "id":"5",
         "from":"Some Other User #1",
         "content":"Some comment"
      },
      {
         "id":"12",
         "from":"Some Other User #2",
         "content":"Some other comment"
      }
   ],
   "posts":[
      {
         "id":"1",
         "title":"My new post",
         "links":{
            "author":"9",
            "comments":[
               "5",
               "12"
            ]
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

In an ordinary response, the `author` and `comments` might be nested in the `posts` key and RestKit can easily connect a relationship from the Post class to an associated Author and/or Comment class so you can do `post.author` and easily get the data you need.  However, if you're not using Core Data and therefore cannot use [RKConnectionDescription](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKConnectionDescription.html), the response shown above does not allow easy mapping this way.

My question is:  If you're using `RKObjectMapping` w/ in-memory objects, is there a way in RestKit to connect a relationship between the `Post` model and the associated `Author` and multiple `Comment` objects?  Ideally, I'd like to have `post.author` that returns an `Author` instance and `post.comments` returns an NSSet or NSArray of `Comment` instances.

I've found a similar issue on the RestKit repo, but no information to work off of there.  I've also researched quite a bit, but I can't come up with a built-in way of doing this using `RKObjectMapping` in RestKit.  Any guidance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Is there a way to do..." what? Can you describe your goal in a bit more detail?

Comment: You've said nothing about what the mapped result should be or what mappings you currently have...

Comment: @Wain Sorry about that!  I just want to be able to have the `posts` have nested `author` and `comments` objects as if it were a normal nested dictionary

Comment: @JoshCaswell Sorry about that, edited the post to clarify

Comment: I've clarified the question a bit, please consider re-opening and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: RestKit supports dynamic mapping as described here https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#dynamic-object-mapping. I'm not sure it fits your problem. Just as possible variant, if you haven't explored it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Have you come across Metadata Mapping as of yet? I believe you can take advantage of the @root key in order to create the connection you're going for (i.e. `@"@root.authors.id"` ).

I can't seem to find direct documentation on this, but you can see the pull [here](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/pull/1435) and there is table in [RestKit For iOS](http://www.packtpub.com/restkit-for-ios/book) if you have / get access.